# Cannot access global store redux when implementing isolated store for specific screen

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I got this error when using useSelector to access variable from global store of Redux.
[image]

But Redux store for specific screen is still available.

Here is my code for specific screen:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  productDetailReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(productDetailWatcher);

interface IProductDetailProps {}

const Product = () => {
  const product = useSelector((state: IProductDetailState) => state.product);
  const products = useSelector((state: IStoreState) => state.productsState.products);

    const dispatch: Dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handlePress = () => {
        const product = {
            id: 1,
            thumbImage: 'https://aladin-today-bucket.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sm/4bd144c7-896c-55db-b70d-7b5a0b2d4638.jpeg',
            thumbHeight: 192,
            productName: 'Váy xường xám mặc Trung Thu,Tết'
        };
        dispatch(GetProductDetailRequest(product));
    }
    
  console.log(`Product Detail 2 render with ${product}`);
  console.log(`Products ${products}`);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={handlePress} title='Get Product Detail' />
      {product && (
        <View style={styles.productContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: product.thumbImage }} />
          <Text style={styles.name}>{product.productName}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const ProductDetail: React.FC<IProductDetailProps> = () => {
    console.log("Product Detail rendering...");

  return <Provider store={store}>
        <Product />
    </Provider>;
};
```

reducer for ProductDetail:

```
import { IProductDetailState, ProductDetailActions, ProductDetailActionType } from './types';
import { ProductModel } from 'models/Product';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { PersistConfig, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

const productDetailState: IProductDetailState = {
    product: undefined,
    loading: false,
}

export const productDetailReducer = (state = productDetailState, action: ProductDetailActions): IProductDetailState => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ProductDetailActionType.GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL_REQUEST: {
            console.log('Enter');
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        }
        case ProductDetailActionType.GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL_SUCCESS: {
            const productDetail: ProductModel = action.payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                product: productDetail,
                loading: false
            }
        }
        case ProductDetailActionType.GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL_FAILURE: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
        default: 
            return {
                ...state
            }
    }
}

const persistConfig: PersistConfig<any> = {
    key: 'ProductDetail',
    whitelist: ['product'],
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    version: 1,
    timeout: 0
};

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, productDetailReducer) as any;
```

Package I use:
"react-native": "0.61.4"
"react-redux": "^7.2.0"
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
Does anyone have any solution? Thank a lot

Comment: Can you also share the code of `productDetailReducer`?

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please review it?

Comment: It looks like your app state has only 2 properties `{ product, loading }` so I'm not sure where your `IStoreState` is created? which means it has no `productsState` in the state

Comment: IStoreState is an interface for global store. This Redux store wrap whole application in App.tsx

Comment: If so, you are now consuming multiple stores. You seem to only be able to achieve the latest store in the tree by using above code

Comment: Absolutely right. Now I can only access the nearest store (isolated store) and cannot access variable from global store. Do you know any solutions for this circumstance? Thank in advance

Comment: Why don't you pass the state you want from app state (probably `productsState ` in this case) to your container of `<ProductDetail />`?

Comment: You mean pass props (aka variables from global store) to component that wrapped by the second store from its parent. Because just parent component of  wrapped component can access variable from global store. Does I miss anything else?

Comment: Yeah that’s possibly the only way to acess the parent store I guess :)

Comment: I think so :D Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is [not advised](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#store-setup) to use multiple stores but react redux connect can use a different store by providing a store prop when rendering the component that connect creates. Here is an example:

```js
const { Provider, useSelector, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;

const store1 = createStore((x) => x, {
  message: 'store 1',
});
const store2 = createStore((x) => x, {
  message: 'store 2',
});
const Messages = ({ message2 }) => {
  //useSelector will use the prop value store from Provider
  const message1 = useSelector((s) => s.message);
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{message1}</li>
      <li>{message2}</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
//connect uses prop store={store2} or store={store1} when
//  MessageContainer does not have a store prop
const MessageContainer = connect(({ message }) => ({
  message2: message,
}))(Messages);
const App = () => {
  return <MessageContainer store={store2} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store1}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So I only can access higher store variables via props from higher component? Is there any solution for accessing to store separately?

Comment: @QuangKhảiĐàm As documentation states and above code shows; `useSelector` always gets state from the store specified in Provider store prop. The `connect` function will use that same store unless the resulting component is rendered with a `store` prop.

Comment: I have tried above solution. Neither connect or useSelector can access global store from the component is wrapped by another store. It means that the component is wrapped by more than 1 store, it can only access variables from nearest store via connect or useSelector. I would like to have a solution for accessing both store from this component. Thank a lot